# symfony knp paginator - always display all results in one page

Tags: php, symfony, pagination

Hello im working in symfony and i decided to use knp paginator.I followed many tutorials and i still can not solve my problem. Pagination doesn't work - always display all results in one page. I also saw that many people have the same issue but nobody answers.

Do you know what should i do ? I will be grateful for every ideas

Here is my code:

```
public function showAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $records = $em->getRepository(Product::class)->findAll();

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $blogPosts = $paginator->paginate(
        $records,
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
        $request->query->getInt('limit', 5)
    );

    return $this->render('article/articles.html.twig', [
        'data' => $records,
        'blog_posts' => $blogPosts,
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    ]);
}
```

twig:

```
<div class="navigation text-center">
    {{ knp_pagination_render(blog_posts) }}
</div>
```

Comment: Is `limit` set correct? `dump($request->query->getInt('limit', 5))`?

Comment: show your twig code

Comment: could it be that you looping through `data` instead `blog_posts` in your twig template?

Comment: Ah sorry, you were right i was looping throught data instead blog_posts. Thanks for your time!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding